# VBA sub for charts returns error 438

Tags: vba, charts

I'm trying to make a sub with a chart parameter:

```
Sub adjustgraph(chrt As Excel.Chart)
    Dim n As Long, m As Long, i As Long
    Dim str As String

    n = chrt.SeriesCollection.Count
    For i = 1 To n
        Debug.Print chrt.SeriesCollection(i).Formula
    Next i

End Sub
```

When trying to run `adjustgraph(activechart)`, I keep getting the error 438 "object doesn't support this property or method". How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251432.aspx

Your method call syntax is incorrect

Use `adjustgraph activechart`

Or `Call adjustgraph(activechart)`